# How to Parse URL with JSON object -Android

Tags: java, android

i have the URL (.com) which has the JSON object .. i created the JSON object using PHP and uploaded in a server so it will be dynamically updated (similar to RSS). I face two problems the first one shows error " and  of type java.Lang.String cannot be converted to JSON object" so i used this code and the error goes:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
 }
```

The SingleMenuItemActivity calss:

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_Title = "Title";
private static final String TAG_Date = "Date";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_Title);
    String description = in.getStringExtra(TAG_Date);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCost.setText(description);

}
 }
```

The AndroidJasonParsingActivity calss:

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// url to make request
private static String url = "http://www.rssparser.host22.com/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Title";
private static final String TAG_Image = "Image";
private static final String TAG_Category = "Category";
private static final String TAG_Venue = "Venue";
private static final String TAG_Date = "Date";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        //contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String Image = c.getString(TAG_Image);
            String Category = c.getString(TAG_Category);
            String Venue = c.getString(TAG_Venue);
            String Date = c.getString(TAG_Date);
            // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_Date);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_Image, Image);
            map.put(TAG_Date , Date );

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_Date }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_Date, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });



}

}
```

Comment: What is your exact error is ? Please post your stacktrace error whichever you are getting.

Comment: The error is :  Value of <HTML><Head> of type java.Lang.String cannot be converted to JSON object

Answer (score 2):

first create JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }
    }
```

then create activity

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // Phone number is agin JSON Object
                JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                map.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and write Internet permission in manifest file

[this is best tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: This is the same code i used above .. i wrote the internet permission and the same error.

Comment: Value of <HTML><Head> of type java.Lang.String cannot be converted to JSON object

Comment: responce get in json format only not in html

Comment: What do you mean ? i did not understand ..